# Is there a way to get a date by calculating just the working days with an argument of number of days or months or years

Tags: php

I am working on this application and I want to get the pay date by just calculating the working days when number of days or months or years is selected like: 10 day(s), 6 month(s), 2 year(s). this below code calculates the days successfully but I need to get only the working days calculated only, thanks for your help

```
function getPayDate( $remittance ) {
    //todays date
    $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
    //split the remittance into %d %s
    $rem = explode(' ', $remittance);

    //$d int %d in numbers
    $d = $rem[0];
    //retrieve string from day(s) month(s) year(s)
    $r = substr($rem[1], 0, -3);

    $date = new DateTime($todayDate);

    //check for days months and years
    switch ($r) {
        case 'day':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P'.$d.'D');
            break;
        case 'month':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P'.$d.'M');
            break;
        case 'year':
            $interval = new DateInterval('P'.$d.'Y');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    
    //add to the interval to the present date
    $date->add($interval);

    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo getPayDate( '25 day(s)' );
```

Comment: How do you work out which are the working days, after all 9 days could be 7 working days or 5.  Also over the years, how do you know about leap years, public holidays and all sorts of other exceptions.

Comment: i don't really know how to go about it, i need help on this

Comment: The point is that everybody's definition of working days is different. You need to come up with some rules defining the working days for your application. You might need to store some info in your database about it. Once you've got some rules and can tell us what they are, it might be easier for us to help. But we can't write code for something when we don't know what the rules are